# Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysqli

Quiero saber qué está fallando en mi código, necesito insertar los datos a una *base de datos* con **pdo** para evitar inyecciones SQL. Ayuda por favor, les dejo el error que me figura:

> ( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
>   ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\Santiago Casas\ext\inmobiliaria\panel\validate\propiedad.php on line 616

```html
//El archivo de conexion

<?php 

  $servername = "127.0.0.1";

  $username = "root";

  $password = "";
  
  $dbname = "santiago_casas";


  // Create connection
  $mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);



 ?>

<?php 

require_once '../inc/session.php';

?>
<?php 

 require_once '../inc/conexion.php';

//-------------------------------------//


$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];

$descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];

$operacion = $_POST['operacion'];

$tipo = $_POST['tipo'];

$habitaciones = $_POST['habitaciones'];

$banos = $_POST['banos'];

$metros = $_POST['metros'];

$ubicacion = $_POST['ubicacion'];

$direccion = $_POST['direccion'];

$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];

$precio = $_POST['precio'];

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];

$inmobiliaria = $_POST['inmobiliaria'];

$moneda = $_POST['moneda'];


// Protejemos los datos contra inyecciones SQL


$titulo = $mysqli->real_escape_string($titulo);

$descripcion = $mysqli->real_escape_string($descripcion);

$operacion = $mysqli->real_escape_string($operacion);

$tipo = $mysqli->real_escape_string($tipo);

$habitaciones = $mysqli->real_escape_string($habitaciones);

$banos = $mysqli->real_escape_string($banos);

$metros = $mysqli->real_escape_string($metros);

$ubicacion = $mysqli->real_escape_string($ubicacion);

$direccion = $mysqli->real_escape_string($direccion);

$telefono = $mysqli->real_escape_string($telefono);

$precio = $mysqli->real_escape_string($precio);

$usuario = $mysqli->real_escape_string($usuario);

$inmobiliaria = $mysqli->real_escape_string($inmobiliaria);

$moneda = $mysqli->real_escape_string($moneda);


 





$sentencia = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO propiedades (titulo, descripcion, operacion, tipo, habitaciones, banos, m2, ubicacion, direccion, telefono, precio, usuario, inmobiliaria, moneda, imagen1, imagen2, imagen3, imagen4, imagen5, imagen6, imagen7, imagen8, imagen9, imagen10, imagen11, imagen12) 

 VALUES (:titulo, :descripcion, :operacion, :tipo, :habitaciones, :banos, :metros, :ubicacion, :direccion, :telefono, :precio, :usuario, :inmobiliaria, :moneda)");

$sentencia->bindParam(':titulo', $titulo);

$sentencia->bindParam(':descripcion', $descripcion);

$sentencia->bindParam(':operacion', $operacion);

$sentencia->bindParam(':tipo', $tipo);

$sentencia->bindParam(':habitaciones', $habitaciones);

$sentencia->bindParam(':banos', $banos);

$sentencia->bindParam(':metros', $metros);

$sentencia->bindParam(':ubicacion', $ubicacion);

$sentencia->bindParam(':direccion', $direccion);

$sentencia->bindParam(':telefono', $telefono);

$sentencia->bindParam(':precio', $precio);

$sentencia->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario);

$sentencia->bindParam(':inmobiliaria', $inmobiliaria);

$sentencia->bindParam(':moneda', $moneda);






// Termino la proteccion de datos contra Inyecciones SQL
 
//Empezamos la consulta INSERT


/*$sql = $mysqli->query("

 INSERT INTO propiedades (titulo, descripcion, operacion, tipo, habitaciones, banos, m2, ubicacion, direccion, telefono, precio, usuario, inmobiliaria, moneda, imagen1, imagen2, imagen3, imagen4, imagen5, imagen6, imagen7, imagen8, imagen9, imagen10, imagen11, imagen12) 

 VALUES ('$titulo', '$descripcion', '$operacion', '$tipo', '$habitaciones', '$banos', '$metros', '$ubicacion', '$direccion', '$telefono', '$precio', '$usuario', '$inmobiliaria', '$moneda', '$imagen1', '$imagen2', '$imagen3', '$imagen4', '$imagen5', '$imagen6', '$imagen7', '$imagen8', '$imagen9', '$imagen10', '$imagen11', '$imagen12')");*/



if ($sentencia) { 

 header("Location: ../propiedades.php");

}else{
 
 header("Location: ../propiedades.php");

}


?>
```

Comment: En MySQLi los marcadores de espacio son con el símbolo de **?** y no con un nombre: **:algo** ya que esto último es de PDO

Answer (score 1):

Realiza los siguientes cambios:

- Los marcadores de posición en *mysqli* se manejan por el símbolo de **`?`** entonces tu **`INSERT`** debe verse de este modo, *aclaro solo coloqué algunos a modo de ejemplo, tu debes colocar el mismo número de marcadores de posición que columnas les vayas a anexar un registro*:

Consulta

```
$sentencia = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO propiedades (titulo, descripcion, 
                                                        operacion, tipo, 
                                                        habitaciones, banos, m2, 
                                                        ubicacion, direccion, 
                                                        telefono, precio, usuario, 
                                                        inmobiliaria, moneda, 
                                                        imagen1, imagen2, imagen3, 
                                                        imagen4, imagen5, imagen6, 
                                                        imagen7, imagen8, imagen9, 
                                                        imagen10, imagen11, 
                                                        imagen12)    
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

- Posterior el método que usa *mysqli* se llama **`bind_param`** y debe contener lo siguiente:

  - Tipo de dato de cada variable
  - Cada variable que contiene el valor a almacenar
  - Puedes pasar todos los valores en una misma línea

Mas o menos puede quedar así:

```
$sentencia->bind_param('ssssss', $variable1, $variable2, $variable3,.....,$variableN);
```

Si almacenas cadenas de texto entonces colocas **`s`**, si vas a almacenar enteros usa **`i`** y si vas a almacenar con decimales entonces **`d`**

**Referencias**

- [documentación *mysqli*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: Ese código no va a funcionar. 1º en la consulta hay 26 columnas, y 14 marcadores `?`. 2º el método `bindParam` no existe en `mysqli`, el método es  `bind_param`. Otra cosa que el OP debe aclarar es de qué tipo son las columnas cuyo nombre comienza por *imagen*, pues si son de tipo BLOB esto va a complicar la cosa. Ya como comentario, es muy cuestionable tener en una tabla una serie de columnas de ese estilo (imagen1, imagen2, imagenN...), quizá el OP debería explicar un poco por qué hace eso para poder sugerirle mejoras en su modelo de datos.

Comment: @A.Cedano estaba precisamente tratando de indicarle que use `bind_param` y termine escribiendo lo que el se supone no debe usar :(

Comment: Respecto a lo de los tipos de datos también tienes razón, decidí dejarlo así solo como un ejemplo y en el enlace de la doc. oficial el puede comprobar de acuerdo con lo que va a almacenar entonces que elija que va a poner

Comment: @A.Cedano concuerdo totalmente contigo, sin embargo en la parte de la recomendación de sus columnas es cierto lo que dices pero si recuerdas en otra pregunta en la cual de hecho me secundaste en la opinión pero el OP decidió que tenía razones para dejarla como estaba *(aunque era obvio que había algunos puntos que estaban erróneos)*, por eso ya no quise aportar en ese punto